# No result when performing port-forwarding

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, client-server, portforwarding

I am currently working with the UNet client-server system in order to do networking and in order to be able to search for all devices on a port beyond LAN as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091976/can-i-use-the-unity-networking-hlapi-without-paying-for-the-unity-multiplayer-se/36092168#36092168) previous question. After searching around I found a suitable C# port-forwarding library from [this](http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/upnp-port-forwarding-the-easy-way/) website and have been following the instructions in order to be able to discover devices on ports. So far I have turned those instructions into the code below.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mono.Nat;

public class PortForwarding : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        NatUtility.DeviceFound += DeviceFound;
        NatUtility.DeviceLost += DeviceLost;


        Debug.Log("Discovery Started");
        NatUtility.StartDiscovery();
    }





    private void DeviceFound(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("DeviceFound");
        INatDevice device = args.Device;
        device.CreatePortMap(new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, 10000, 10000));
        // Can be .Udp or Tcp but both create no results
        foreach (Mapping portMap in device.GetAllMappings())
        {
            Debug.Log(portMap.ToString());
        }
        // on device found code
    }

    private void DeviceLost(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
    {
        INatDevice device = args.Device;

        // on device disconnect code
    }


}
```

In my scene I have three empty GameObjects each with a script, one is to create a server, the second creates a client and the other is to test port-forwarding (the first two scripts are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676231/unity-how-to-find-a-server-from-client-using-networkdiscovery?noredirect=1#comment64732703_38676231)). Unfortunately I am getting no result, hence today I am asking you where have I gone wrong and how could I use this library to discover clients or servers beyond LAN.

If I have missed any details out or you require more in order to solve my problem just ask.

[image]

Comment: I am looking into this and will let you if I find anything useful

Comment: Thanks, it seems an easy method of discovery

Comment: I tried your code and it works. It's good to subscribe to an event once instead of every frame. Putting `NatUtility.DeviceFound += DeviceFound;` in the update function is not a good idea. I updated your code to fix that. Attach the updated code in your question to a gameobject and tell me what log you saw.

Comment: @Programmer I am getting no change in logs, I'm uploading a picture of them (when using your code). If necessary i can get a screen video of my setup as you said it was working for you.

Comment: You are not getting any log at-all? You are not even getting `Discovery Started` log? Attach the script to a gameobject that is enabled....

Comment: No change in logs from the previous code that I was using, the picture is now attached above

Comment: Please disable any other script running. Just let this only this script run until the problem is solved. Also where did you put the `Mono.Nat.dll` file?

Comment: In the assets, still I am getting no device found log. I'm trying it in a new project with a single empty object

Comment: What unity version and What Os version?

Comment: Unity 5.3.4f1 Personal

Comment: Windows 10 (Version 1511?)

Comment: Open up firewall and make sure that Unity is not blocked.You can google hoe to do this on Win10. Also update to Unity 5.4 since that's the version I am using.

Comment: Should I need to open up my firewall in the first place as would the user do that anyway? It should work with firewall shouldn't it...

Comment: No, but sometimes, firewall automatically blocks an application. It happens sometimes but it is easier for users to unblock firewall than for them to manually perform port-forwarding in the router setting.

Comment: Have done both and still the logs do not change @Programmer