# How to connect networkig player with internet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I just followed a guide about [**Basic UNet Tut Here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlKf0h0K5PU), Its spawning network car player which can be controlled by local player. I can make or join server through built-in **Network Manager HUD** which is provided by the unity along with Network Manager component. **I am able to run and connect application on my LAN on different PCs but failed to connect it on other network**. I don't know what are the reasons. Do I need to make or purchase a server for it or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: bro same problem with me did u get the solution??? if yes please help me too.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/working-over-lan-now-how-do-i-connect-over-internet.180001/

Comment: with this can we connect to players on different network?? i mean over Internet and not just LAN.

Comment: You should do NAT punchthrough but it is difficult. You can purchase Unity Network service for this

Comment: Bro I am new to Unity Networking. Some help will be Appreciated. Please help me to do so

Comment: read this https://forum.unity.com/threads/unet-and-nat-punchthrough-it-can-be-done.391845/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154578/discussion-between-veeresh-kumbar-and-mohammad-faizan-khan).

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, Unity offers *free* hosting for online games (There are some constraints).

- You need to login to Unity control panel and activate it.

There is great tutorial/documentation about this there.

I don't remember the specifics but basically, in your control panel you're going to get an address that you can put in your Network Manager, then you should be available to connect to your game from another network.

Comment: There is ip address field. I put the IP but unable to connect