# Unity UNet Queries

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, mmo, unity3d-unet

I recently started working on UNet basically on a MMO game. My setup is that I am hosting my own dedicated server by building a linux headless build and uploading and running it on the server. All the clients are connected to it and this server keeps on running 24/7. Following are my questions:

1. Upto my understanding I do not have to pay anything to UNet as I am not using their match making and am hosting my own server. Is this correct?
2. There is no limit of number of concurrent users. Limit depends upon how powerful the dedicated server is. Correct?
3. In NetworkManager, under advanced configuration, I have set maximum connections to 1000. This means it can handle 1000 concurrent users?
4. UNet API is used for Client/Server calls and no Unity Server is used. Correct?

Thank you.

Comment: did you ever used UNET?

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that " Irecently started working on UNet"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092168/4783560

Comment: Thanks @shadowlif