# (Unity) NetworkManager how many clients can connect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, server

I've got a real server and how to connect NetworkManager to this server? How many clients can handle at time? Can this handle  million clients at time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NetworkManager how many clients can connect?

It used to be about 16 when UNet was newly released. I don't know if that changed before 5.6 release.

After *Unity 5.6* release, that increaded to 128. So the current maximum connection is 128.

Quote from *Unity 5.6.0* [release note](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0):

> Multiplayer: Up to 128 UDP sockets are now supported.

For the rest of you question, you can always look on Unity website. It has many examples. You can connect to a server with [`Network.Connect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Connect.html).

Comment: I cannot find any examples how to connect my to server. The all examples were been about connect with **localhost**. ..and can I increase that number of clients ?

Comment: You cannot increase it above 128. If you want to do that then build your own network API with UDP and TCP. As for connecting to a non local server, you have to use Unity's server or implement it yourself with NAT or a relay. This is a complicated subject I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091976/can-i-use-the-unity-networking-hlapi-without-paying-for-the-unity-multiplayer-se/36092168?s=3|0.6729#36092168). You need somebody with networking background to do this for you or you should be willing to learn a-lot.

Comment: Please avoid asking many questions in one question. Keep it simple then create new question if you have other questions.

Comment: [Please help me for this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126244/cannot-create-json-file-to-resources-folder)