# Cannot create json file to resources folder

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

In my unity project I have `Resources` folder. I tried to create json file into `Resources` folder. But when I run the unity it says `ArgumentException:....`. I tried to use `Application.dataPath` .It successfully created in unity editor...in android it is not working. The reason why I use `Resources` Because I successfully read json file (which is already created) in android but I cannot create **json** file.

This is my **simple** `Ciop.cs` script

```
    using System.IO;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using LitJson;
    public class Ciop : MonoBehaviour {

        private JsonData itemData;
        private baaaaza nj;

        void Start () {

            nj = new baaaaza("eshhak");
            string jsn = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Rr").text;
            itemData = JsonMapper.ToJson(nj);
            File.WriteAllText(jsn, itemData.ToString());
        }  
  }
    public class baaaaza
    {
        public string Name;
        public baaaaza(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't write to the Resources folder during run-time. It is read-only and must be read with the [Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276) API. For multiple-platform compatibly saving, save to `Application.persistentDataPath+"YourFolder"`...See the dup for an example.

Comment: which is faster `playerprefs` or `json`?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense when you compare playerprefs and json. playerprefs  saves data. json does not save file. It serializes a class/data then `File.ReadAllBytes` is used to save it. Maybe you meant to compare playerprefs  and File.ReadAllBytes? The speed of these shouldn't matter. Doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: I think the best choice is `playerpref`. It  is working on android well and very easy! I know it cannot be more than 1mb.

Comment: I won't argue over the two. Use whatever suits you.